# combine the whole elements in the array and store it in index 0

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have an array of values:

```
array1[] = {1, 32, 4, 12};
```

Which I want to store as a string of hexadecimal representations of each value (with format `"%02x"`) :

```
string = "0120040c";
```

I can print the string using a `for` loop just fine:

```
for (int i=0;i<array_size;++i)
    printf("%02x", array[i]);
```

But haven't been able to assign the resulting string to a char array. How can I do this?

Comment: C is 0-based, change to `array1[0] = 'a'` (note `'` instead of `"`), and `array2[1] = "apple"`should be `array2[6] = "apple"`or `array2[] = "apple"`

Comment: Your two alternatives are very different things. Also show us how `array1`and `arary2` are declared.

Comment: Unclear what you want.

Comment: There are a zillion very good tutorials/FAQs/... about how C string work. Read these first please.

Comment: I am googling all day but nothing yet.

Comment: @JasperKanbier See my answer updated!

Comment: So I want to copy the first 6 elements of a array1 to the first element of array2

Comment: @Jasper Kanbier My answer contains all you need even if it is unclear what you want.:)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Can "apple" be replaced by (arrayname)?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the array is a hex array, so if I want to printf the content I need to for loop 'printf("%02x",array[arraysize];' the lenght is fixed, so what I want is to output the whole array to a string.

Comment: @JasperKanbier: concatenate it onto a VLA char array: `char string[arraysize*2 + 1];` in loop: `snprintf(string+(i*2), 3, "%02x", array[i]);`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I think I am on the right track with your last comment!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem This works! I only need to add a \0 to the string in order to use is later in a strcmp.

Comment: @JasperKanbier: I've edited your question to reflect on what you _actually_ want, because what you said in the comments is miles apart from what your initial question lead everyone to believe (hence the down-votes, close-votes and barrage of comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want to create a string showing the values in an array as hexadecimals. This can be done, relatively easily by looping over the string, and with some `snprintf` magic. But first, let's establish what we need to know, and how to obtain that info:

- Why size is the array
- How many chars will each value take up in our target string
- How are we accessing the array, as an array or a pointer (ie: is it passed to a function or not)

If you have a compiler that supports C99 or C11, you can use a VLA. First, let's assume that you have an array (And not a pointer):

```
const char * format = "%02x";//each value will be 2 chars + terminating 0
int array[] = { 123, 32, 4354, 544};
size_t arr_len = sizeof array/ sizeof *array;//get the nr of elements in the array
char string[arr_len*2 + 1];//nr of array elements *2 (chars) + terminating 0
for (int i=0;i<arr_len;++i)
{//this is where the magic happens:
    snprintf(string + (i*2), 3, format, array[i]);
}
printf("The full hex string is: %s\n", string);
```

Now let's look at this bit: `snprintf(string + (i*2), 3, format, array[i]);`

I'm using the `string` array, as if it were a pointer, as if `string` contained a memory address pointing to `string[0]`. By adding `i*2` to it, I'm telling `snprintf` that the target memory to where it should write the output starts at the N-th element of the array. On the first iteration, `i` is 0, so `string + 0*2 == string + 0 == string`, the second time, it's `string + (1*2) == string + 2 == &string[2]`. Effectively, concatenating the output.

Then, I pass 3 to `snprintf`, telling the function that the max length of the output is 3 chars (**including the terminating `\0` char**). That's a perfect fit for the 2 hex chars + `\0` coming from our format `"%02x"`. Then it's a simple matter of passing `array[i]` to add the hex value to the end of the string.

---

Great, now what if `array` is passed to a function, and/or you don't have VLA's? same as above, with a few differences. You'll have to compute and pass the length of the array to the function (computation method shown above). You'll also have to allocate the memory for the string yourself (and free it), which shouldn't be too difficult either:

```
char * get_hex_string(int *arr, size_t arr_len)
{
    char * string = malloc((arr_len * 2 + 1) * sizeof *string);//the sizeof *string is optional
    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;
    string[0] = '\0';//clear first char, just in case
    for (int i=0;i<arr_len;++i)
        snprintf(string + i*2, 3, "%02x", arr[i]);//same as before
    string[arr_len*2] = '\0';//optional, just a habit of mine
    return string;//return string
}

int main( void )
{
    int array[] = {12, 32, 54, 1, 6};
    char *as_string = get_hex_string(array, sizeof array/sizeof *array);
    if (as_string == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get hex-string\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    printf("Hex-string: %s\n", as_string);
    free(as_string);//optional here, but good habit
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## [Demo](https://eval.in/218683)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *join(int n, char *a[n]){
    int i;
    size_t lens[n], len=1;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        len += (lens[i] = strlen(a[i]));
    char *cat = malloc(len);
    char *p = cat;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        memcpy(p, a[i], lens[i]+1);
        p += lens[i];
    }
    return cat;
}

int main(void){
    char *array1[] = {"a", "p", "p", "l", "e"};
    char *string;
    int n = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(*array1);
    string = join(n, array1);
    puts(string);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you then the definition of a two-dimensional array will look like

```
char a[M][N] = { "apple" };
```

where M and N some integral constants that specifies sizes of the array. (In C you may use also Varaiable Length Arrays if the compiler supports them)

Or if you want to copy the first array in the first element of a two dimensional array defined like above then you need to write

```
memcpy( a[0], array1, 5 );
a[0][5] = '\0';
```

If array1 would contain a zero terminated string then you could use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy`

Note
I think you mean for example

```
array1[0] = 'a';
```

instead of

```
array1[0] = "a"
```

If so then the code can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) 
{
    char array1[5];
    char array2[10][6];

    array1[0] = 'a';
    array1[1] = 'p';
    array1[2] = 'p';
    array1[3] = 'l';
    array1[4] = 'e';

    memcpy( array2[0], array1, 5 );
    array2[0][5] = '\0';

    printf( "array2[0] = %s\n", array2[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise if array1 is a two-dimensional array itself then you should use standard function `strcat` and the code could look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char array1[5][2] = { "a", "p", "p", "l", "e" };
    char array2[10][6] = { { '\0' } };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) strcat( array2[0], array1[i] );

    printf( "array2[0] = %s\n", array2[0] );
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases the output will be

```
apple
```

Or if the second array is a one dimensional array then you can write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char array1[5][2] = { "a", "p", "p", "l", "e" };
    char string[6] = { '\0' };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) strcat( string, array1[i] );

    printf( "string = %s\n", string );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the last example is what i need, but it segfaults at the moment.

Comment: @Jasper Kanbier Your segfault has nothing common with the code examples I showed. Maybe you forgot to initialize with zero the destination string.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear why you've written `array2[0]`, that implies that `array2` should be an array of strings, declared like so:

```
char array2[N][M];
```

Where N is at least 1 and `M` is at least 6 to hold `"apple\0"`.

If you just meant that `array2` should be a single string, declared like so:

```
char array2[32];
```

for instance, then you can create that by copying the characters from `array1` and then ending the string by putting in the `'\0'` character at the end:

```
memcpy(array2, array1, 5);
array2[5] = '\0';
```

At this point, doing e.g. `printf("'%s'\n", array2);` will print `'apple'`.

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 6

int main() {

    char array1[MAX_SIZE];
    char array2[1][MAX_SIZE];

    array1[0] = 'a';
    array1[1] = 'p';
    array1[2] = 'p';
    array1[3] = 'l';
    array1[4] = 'e';
    //...


    array1[MAX_SIZE-1] = '\0';

    strcpy(array2[0], array1);

    array2[0][MAX_SIZE-1] = '\0';

    printf("%s", array2[0]);

    return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: A string needs to be null terminated, there's no null termination in array1!

Comment: Wrong because you need 6 `char`'s to store `"apple"`! So the `strcpy()` will give undefined behavior.

Comment: Oke but apple was just a example, content of array1 is changing in a while loop.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham, meaning-matters, Jasper Kanbier updated my answer!

Comment: @Rizier123 In my code array1 is part of a while loop, and the content is changing, in fact thousands of fruits..;-) So the conversion needs to be part of the loop.